# What is the correct way to implement a "clone" method in languages that do not support type reflection and have no built-in cloning mechanism?

Tags: clone

### Problem background

Suppose I have a class called Transaction and a subclass called NetTransaction.  The Transaction class implements a clone method which constructs a new Transaction with multiple constructor parameters.

Such a cloning pattern presents a problem for subclasses like NetTransaction, because calling super.clone will return an object of type Transaction which cannot be up casted to NetTransaction.  Therefore, I'd have to reimplement (duplicate) the code in the Transaction class's clone method.  Obviously, this is an unacceptable pattern.

### Java's solution -- works for languages with built-in cloning logic or type reflection

In Java (so I've read), calling super.clone always returns an object of the correct type as long as every override in the chain calls super.clone, because the base Object's clone method will automatically return an object of the correct type, presumably a feature built into the runtime.

The existence of such a clone method implies that every clonable object must have a parameterless default constructor (either explicitly or implicitly) for two reasons.  Firstly, Object's implementation would not be capable of choosing an arbitrary constructor for a subclass it knows nothing about, hence the need for a parameterless constructor.  Secondly, although a copy constructor might be the next logical choice, it implies that every object in the class chain would also have to have a copy constructor, otherwise every copy constructor would be faced with the same decision as clone (i.e. to call the default constructor or a copy constructor).  That ultimately implies that all the cloning logic would have to be in copy constructors, which would make overriding "clone" unnecessary; therefore, we arrive at the logical conclusion that it would be self-defeating to have clone call anything other than a parameterless default constructor (i.e. the runtime would have to create an instance that require no special construction logic to run).

So Java's cloning implementation, which also seems to provide some built-in shallow copying, is one way to implement cloning that makes sense.

### Correct alternative for languages without built-in cloning or type reflection?

But what about other languages that don't have such built-in functionality and lack type reflection?  How should they implement cloning?  Are copy constructors the only way to go?

I think the only way that really makes sense is copy constructors, and as far as implementing or overriding a clone method for the sake of returning a common interface or base type or just "object", the correct implementation is to simply always call the current object's copy constructor.  Is this correct?

The pattern would be, in C# for example:

```
class A
{
    public A( A original_to_copy ) { /*copy fields specific to A*/ }
    public object clone() { return new A( this ); }
}

class B: A
{
    public B( B original_to_copy ):this (original_to_copy) { /*copy fields specific to B*/ }
    public override object clone() { return new B( this ); }
}

class C: B
{
    public C( C original_to_copy ):this(original_to_copy) { /*copy fields specific to C*/ }
    public override object clone() { return new C( this ); }
}
```

Comment: I'm not the one voting to close, but what's wrong with the code that you currently posted?  That's the most straightforward solution to what you are trying to do.  The only improvement I can think of is to turn A into an abstract base class called Cloneable.

Comment: I presented a core programming problem, an existing solution for one type of language, and a logical reasoning for why it exists and why it takes a certain form, and I also presented an alternative that should work for other types of languages, but I could be missing something.  Perhaps someone who has formally studied computer science knows whether there is or is not some other pattern that is better.  I've looked at other questions similar to this, but they don't give a clear answer and they're all dealing with Java exclusively.

Comment: Bottom line is, with this question, as written, even if someone just answered "YES, that's the best", this question would be more valuable than any of the other related ones on this site I've read, because it more clearly explains the problem, addresses all the pitfalls, alternatives, uses logic to describe why things are the way they are, offers a generic solution, and ultimately answers the question.

Comment: The best answer is highly dependent on the language you are using and what you are trying to optimize - readability/maintenainability?  static-type-safety?  run-time speed? run-time flexibility?  If you are using a multi-paradigm language like C++, I can, off the top of my head, think of at least 5 different approaches.  However, the sample code you have listed is the most straightforward and most likely to be understood by the greatest number of people.  Which is "best" depends on too many factors (including language of choice): your question is not specific enough.

Comment: There are really only two kinds of approaches.  Even if you're allocating memory for an object directly and stamping the bytes in place from an image, it all comes down to cloning via a constructor (i.e. the object type and memory are allocated in advance) or using some base object implementation that is capable of instantiating the correct type via reflection.  I would love to see a case where the latter outperforms the former under any circumstance.  Since we're implicitly talking about object-oriented languages, the solution is a least-common denominator approach... cloning via constructor.

Comment: Even within object-oriented languages, I was very specific about needing an approach that does not require the language to have a built-in cloning method or reflection.  That pretty much narrows it down to copy constructors or variants thereof, which essentially boils down to allocating the class instance and leveraging superclass methods for populating the object.  I haven't seen an approach that is faster, cleaner, or easier to maintain than a copy constructor.  If one exists, post it.

Answer (score 0):

In systems without a built-in cloning facility, there's really no alternative to using a virtual clone method chain to a copy constructor.  I would suggest, however, that one should have the copy constructor and virtual cloning method be `protected`, and have the base-class copy constructor throw an exception if the *exact types* of the passed-in object does not match the exact type of the object under construction.  Public cloning methods should not be virtual, but should instead chain to the virtual method and cast the result to their own type.

When practical, one should avoid having classes which expose public cloning methods be inheritable; consumers should instead refer to class instances using interface types.  If some of the consumers of a type will need to clone it and others won't, some potential derivatives of the type could not logically be cloned, and if a derivative of the type which wasn't cloneable should be usable by code that doesn't need to clone it, splitting things that way will allow for the existence of BaseFoo, CloneableBaseFoo, FancyFoo, and CloneableFancyFoo types; code which needs fancy abilities but doesn't need to clone an object will be able to accept FancyFoo and CloneableFancyFoo objects, while code that doesn't need a fancy object but needs cloning ability will be able to accept CloneableBaseFoo and CloneableFancyFoo objects.